# React native NAVITE BASE picker how to disable picker item

Tags: react-native, picker, native-base

I'm using the native base picker package for react-native.

I want to disable some items but, `enable disable params` don't work, all elements are still selectable.

I'm testing the app in ios. Here's my code

```
import { Picker } from 'native-base';

<Picker
              iosHeader="VALUES"
              mode="dropdown"
              style={{ margin: 0, padding: 0 ,width:180,color:"#fff", justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center" , textAlign:"center" }}
              placeholder="Select one"
              placeholderStyle={{ color: "#fff" }}
              placeholderIconColor="#fff"
              headerBackButtonText="Back"
              headerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#ff705a" }}
              headerTitleStyle={{ color: "white" }}
              headerBackButtonTextStyle={{ color: "white" }}
              selectedValue={this.state.selectedVal}
              onValueChange={(value) => this.onchange(value)}
              textStyle={{ textAlign:"center" }}
              textStyle={{color:"#fff"}}
              
            >
            <Picker.Item  value='' label='Select' />
            <Picker.Item label="SELECT ONE" value="34" />

</Picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Picker](https://docs.nativebase.io/migration/picker) component was officially replaced with [Select](https://docs.nativebase.io/select) in the update of v2 to v3 of NativeBase.  Hope this still helps you! I wasnt able to get the Picker component to work on Expo Snack ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Below is an example I found in the docs. By adding the `isDisabled` prop to `<Select.Item />` for `C` and `Java`. This prop prevents the ability to choose these options on iOS and Android. In my testing this did not work on Web.

```
<Select
    selectedValue={value}
    _selectedItem={{
        bg: "red.600",
        endIcon: <CheckIcon size={5} />,
    }}
>
    <Select.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
    <Select.Item label="TypeScript" value="ts" />
    <Select.Item label="C" value="c" isDisabled />
    <Select.Item label="Python" value="py" />
    <Select.Item label="Java" value="java" isDisabled />
</Select>
```

[Full working code example in Snack here](https://snack.expo.dev/@brashkinfink/hazardous-cookie-2)